# Search Filter, should I do it client side or server side?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, filtering

I have a search form that returns a list of results, I also have a filter area where the user can filter down the results (price etc). My question is, should I be doing the filtering through client side javascript or should I do it serverside within the MYSQL select?

The issue is, the filtering will have quite a few levels, so when putting this into a mysql select could become quite tedious.

Comment: `..., so when putting this into a mysql select could become quite tedious.`. This should **never** be a reason to move a piece of serverside code to the client.

Answer (score 18):

It depends on if you are using **pagination** or not

If you don't paginate your search result, but returning every row to the client, you should filter client side since you know have all data clientside.

If your search result is paginated, just showing first e.g.10 search results, a filter need to be done server side to include all paginated rows not yet in client.

Answer (score 10):

It really depends on the nature of your application:

- how much data is there?
- how often do you query it?
- how often does the page need to be reloaded?

E.g. Facebook sends you your *whole* list of friend names, so when you type someones name in a comment, the client-side app notices it (and proposes you an automated completion). It's done client-side because:

- the whole amount of data is relatively small (1000 friend names * 20 bytes each ~= 20kB of data, less than most images on a website. gzip it and it's even less).
- it's queried A LOT, practically every time someone presses a key in a text box
- most of the things in the application can be done without leaving, and therefore reloading, the page; the data has to be loaded only once.

Generally speaking, letting the client do more work means that your application may scale more easily, since the more users you get, the more "cpu power" you get.

Answer (score 3):

You should realize the consequences if you put it in client side.

1. You may have to pass far more data through the Internet than you want.
2. You may not be able to use some good stuff of MySQL like index or cache to optimize your results. These well designed and tested functions are always better than yours.

However, I think it's perfectly OK to do this on the client side if you are cool with these consequences.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand point 1.

The way I was initially thinking was,

MYSQL select will return results using MATCH() against()

the user will also after this point have an option to filter the already returned rows. So it's not like they're searching new content rather filtering what's already been returned.

Comment: @user863739 You may waste much traffic if the client side filter filtered away plenty of results which users would never see or expect to see. But if the users want full information, and would filter it for many times like to see the differences, client filter is right choice.

Answer (score 0):

It should be server side in your SQL.

Something like SELECT * WHERE price > 100

If you do it in the client side, you need to send to much data from server to client.

Comment: On the other hand, depending on the data size, leveraging on the client can be advantegeous because the data only has to be transferred once.

Comment: Well I was thinking more of the lines, return all rows,

Then use jQuery to filter the data (hide, show)

Comment: It depends. If user will use filtering often then having the data on client side means that less data will be transfered and that the application will be more responsive. On the other hand the initial transfer and load can be slow especially when there is a large amount of unfiltered data.

Comment: Well the MYSQL will return around 100-200 rows of data. No imagery only text. The filtering was a way to navigate the already returned rows.